# Histogram: 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram

I am currently working on a statical analysis using histogram. However, when I try to plot the histogram of the data, an "x must be numeric" error appeared.

```
x < - c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y < - c(1, 5, 7, 21, 34)

DATA <- data.frame(x,y)
plot(hist(y ~ x, DATA, breaks = 50))
```

I try different solutions found on the Stack Overflow community, yet nothing works for my codes. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `barplot`? `barplot(y ~ x, DATA)` should work, but it doesn't take a `breaks` argument.  A histogram is a density estimate of a single variable. `hist` expects it's first argument to be a single vector, e.g. `hist(DATA$x)` but you're giving it a formula of 2 variables. And `hist` doesn't take a data argument. See `?hist` for argument list, examples, and details. If the barplot isn't what you want, please describe in more detail the plot you're trying to make.

Comment: (And, both `barplot` and `hist` draw a plot by default, you don't need to wrap them in `plot()`.)

Comment: From what I can tell, your `x` and `y` is count. As Gregor Thomas mentioned, `hist()` takes in just one vector. For example, if `x` really is your variable and `y` is count, you could do: `x1 <- rep(x, y)   ;   hist(x1)`

Comment: Also, the way you use the assigment operator is wrong: `< -`; there must not be a space in between!